# ubuntu 16.04 do-release-upgrade: no new release May 2, 2018

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I have /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades set to lts and here it is 2 days after 18.04 has been released and I am still getting "no new release". What gives fellas? 
i am running 16.04 32bit server if that matters.